# How to process new records only from file?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-structured-streaming

I have a scenario to process records from a file. Data in the file are added periodically (every milliseconds). So i need to read the file and process it and at the same time process only newly added records.

I came across the concepts of Spark Structured streaming which is built on Spark SQL. What i am doing is -

1. Trigger the file stream processing every 1 second
2. Run the Spark SQL Query on the file
3. Write the output of the query on console in append mode.

Below is the code for the same -

```java
public static class SparkStreamer implements Runnable,Serializable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        processDataStream();

    }

    private void processDataStream() {

        Dataset<Row> rowData = spark.readStream().format("Text").load("C:\\Test\\App\\");

        Dataset<String> data = rowData.as(Encoders.STRING()).flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {

            @Override
            public Iterator<String> call(String row) throws Exception {
                return Arrays.asList(row.split("\\|")).iterator();
            }


        },Encoders.STRING());

        Dataset<Row> dataCount = data.select(new Column("value"));


        StreamingQuery query = dataCount.writeStream()
                  .outputMode("append")
                  .format("console")
                  .start();
        try {
            query.awaitTermination();
        } catch (StreamingQueryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

With the above implementation, query is executed 1 time but then if i add new records in the file, second batch execution is not getting triggered.

Other observations:

- With output mode as complete & updated there is no output. Only with append mode, I am getting output 1 time.

Can someone help to address this issue ? Does Spark Structured Streaming supports processing data from file, since normal Spark Streaming doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

> Does Spark Structured Streaming supports processing data from file

Yes.

> query is executed 1 time but then if i add new records in the file, second batch execution is not getting triggered.

That's not going to work as right after a file has been processed once it is marked as seen and never processed again (review [FileStreamSource](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/streaming/FileStreamSource.scala#L35) that is responsible for it to find how it works under the covers).

The recommended solution is to write new content to a new file.