# Spark Structured Streaming Processing Previous Files

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am implementing the file source in [Spark Structures Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#input-sources) and want to process the same file name again if the file has been modified.  Basically an update to the file.  Currently right now Spark will not process the same file name again once processed.  Seems limited compared to Spark Streaming with [Dstream](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html).  Is there a way to do this? Spark Structured Streaming doesn't document this anywhere it only process new file with different names.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is somewhat of an anti pattern, but you may be able to dig through the checkpoint data and remove the entry for that original file.

Try looking for the original file name in the /checkpoint/sources/*/* files delete the file or entry. That might cause the stream to pick up the file name again. I haven't tried this myself.

If this is a one time manual update, I would just change the file name to something new and drop it in the source directory. This approach won't be maintainable or automated.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion it will only work once the checkpoint/source files has been deleted and re-starting the stream.  It appears the only work around is to create a new file name to re-process the data.  There's a similar post (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45086501/how-to-process-new-records-only-from-file).